# Using comparison operators in SELECT clause of T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, comparison-operators

How to select a result of comparison operator as a field with type BIT?

How it does work in `C#`:

```
bool isGreater = FieldA > FieldB;
```

How it doesn't work in `T-SQL`:

```
SELECT (FieldA > FieldB) AS BIT FROM t
```

How to write such task properly?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You should use CASE clause:

```
CASE
    WHEN FieldA > FieldB THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS [BIT]
```

Answer (score 45):

```
Select Convert(Bit, Case When FieldA > FieldB Then 1 Else 0 End) As YourBitColumn
```

If you want to return a BIT, then you need the convert (or cast) to a bit data type, otherwise, SQL would interpret the hard coded constant (1 or 0) as an integer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `IIF` function. For example:

```
SELECT IIF(FieldA > FieldB, 1, 0) AS YourBitColumn FROM t
```

`IFF` Function's syntax like as below:

```
IIF( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
```

`IFF` returns, If `boolean_expression` is true, then `true_value`, otherwise `false_value`

For more information about `IFF` function : [Logical Functions - IIF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)